# How to query with double belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models:

Event, Place, Location

```
Event:
  belongs_to :place

Place:
  belongs_to :location

Location:
  has_many :places
```

I want to find all events where Location's `city` attribute is 'New York'. What's the best way of doing it with Rails4 and Postgres ?

Answer (score 2):

This should do

```
Event.includes({ place: :locations }).where(locations: {city: 'New York'}).references(:locations)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Event.joins(:place => :location).where("locations.city = ?", "New York")
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to make use of [nested associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations) (section 12.2.3 specifically)

```
Event.joins(places: :locations).where('locations.city = ?', 'New York')
```